# How do you add column borders for a Shiny datatable?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have a shiny datatable that looks like this:

[image]

However, I want it to have full borders around all of the cells to make it look more like an excel sheet. I know in the shiny table it is as simple as calling `bordered = T` but that does not work for the datatable in Shiny.

This is my UI code:

```
      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("stats_table", width = "95%")
      )
```

And this is my server code:

```
output$stats_table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
  # Do not show a plot when the page first loads
  # Wait until the user clicks "Plot" button
  if (input$plot_graph_button == 0)
    return()

  data <- summary_table
  #### Do some filtering here ####
  data

}))
```

Thank you in advance for the help, I feel like this should be a very easy fix, however, I am not finding any good information on it. I do realize this is purely cosmetic and does not effect the functionality of the table.

Comment: It is much easier to help if you include a minimum reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think this question has already been answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751568/add-cell-borders-in-an-r-datatable/50754794#50754794  . Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Aureliencallens I tried that code and it actually does not work with the syntax I have. I did see that example before posting my question. It is close to what I need but not quite correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cell-border stripe` class. Check [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) for more options

```
 output$stats_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
               # Do not show a plot when the page first loads
               # Wait until the user clicks "Plot" button
               # if (input$plot_graph_button == 0)
               # return()

       data <- datatable(head(iris), class = 'cell-border stripe')
       #### Do some filtering here ####
       data

})
```