# R Shiny renderTable - how to change borders width and color

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I probably have a simple question but since I'm not very familiar with CSS/htlm I'm having a hard time to figure out the following problem.
In my ui I have the following simple table:

```
tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table")
```

in the server, I have this very simple code:

```
output$retail_dashboard_ratios_table <- renderTable({  #
df <- head(mtcars)
})
```

All I would need to do is to set the borders width and borders color (to blue).
I'm obliged to use the R 3.4 version. 
Since I have a static tableOutput, I cannot (apparently) use solution mentioned in [Add Cell Borders in an R Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751568/add-cell-borders-in-an-r-datatable/50754794#50754794)
because I cannot return a datatable object.

I also read [R shiny renderTable change cell colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798941/r-shiny-rendertable-change-cell-colors) that has a very interesting solution, but given my R version, it seems library(tableHTML) is not compatible.

I wonder if anybody has a simple solution simply to fix the borders.
Thanks

---

Thanks to @Patrick Altmeyer this is the final working solution!

```
source("global.R") 

today <- as.character()

ui <- dashboardPage(  
  title = "Dashboard of the Municipal Market",  # this is the name of the tab in Chrome browserr
  dashboardHeader(title = "Web Portal"),

  dashboardSidebar(   
    sidebarMenu(

      menuItem('Retail', tabName = "retail", icon = icon("th"),
               menuItem('Dashboard', tabName = 'retail_dashboard'))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody( 
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard",
              tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                          tabPanel("Dashboard",
                                   h3("Test."),

                                   tags$head(
                     tags$style(HTML("
                                                .my_table_aa01 .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
                                                border-collapse: collapse;
                                                }

                                                .my_table_aa01 th {
                                                 border: 1px solid black !important;
                                                 text-align: center !important;
                                                 vertical-align: middle !important;
                                                 color: white !important;
                                                 background-color: #615858 !important;
                                                 white-space: nowrap;
                                                 border-bottom: none}

                                                .my_table_aa01 td {padding: 1rem;
                                                border: 1px solid black;}

                                                .my_table_aa01 tr:first-child {
                                                  border : 1px solid black;
                                                 border-top: 1px solid black;}

                                                 .my_table_aa01 tr:nth-child(even){
                                                 background-color: #afd19d;
                                                 color: black;
                                                 font-size:16px;}

                                                 .my_table_aa01 tr:nth-child(odd){
                                                 background-color: white;
                                                 color: black;
                                                 font-size:16px;
                                                 }
                                                "))),

                                   fluidRow(column(2,
                                                   actionButton(inputId = "retail_dashboard_load_data_btn", label = "Load / Refresh Data")),
                                            column(2,
                                                   downloadButton("download_dashboard_data","Download Data"))),

                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(2, 
                                            dateInput("retail_dashboard_start_dt", label = ("Start Date"), value = glob_date_1yr_ago)),
                                     column(2, 
                                            dateInput("retail_dashboard_end_dt", label = ("End Date"), value = glob_previous_to_most_recent_date_with_quant_model_regression_data))
                                   ),


                                   br(),
                                   fluidRow(column(6,
                                                   div(textOutput(outputId = "retail_dashboard_error_log")))),
                                   br(),

                                   fluidRow(column(3,
                                                   plotlyOutput(outputId = "retail_dashboard_plot1", width = '350', height = '350px')),
                                            column(3,
                                                   offset = 0,
                                                   tags$div(
                                                     class="my_table_aa01", # set to custom class
                                                     tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table") )


                                            )),
                                   fluidRow(column(3,
                                                   tableOutput("retail_dashboard_table2")))
                                     )
                                     )             
              )
              )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {    
  source("Page_retail_dash.R", local=T) 


}

cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @SusanSwitzer great question. Please, allow me to explain. My real goal is to have in a single "row" both a small plot as well as a small table.
I tried to achieve that goal by using
fluidRow(
column(3,  plotlyOutput(outputId = "retail_dashboard_plot1", width = '350', height = '350px')),
column(3,
                                       offset = 0,
                                       dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table"),
                                       ))
but the layout gets completely screwed up

Comment: @SusanSwitzer in reality tableOutput is probably all I need, I'm just trying to figure out how to customize the borders. So far I managed to update the code in the ui to:
tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table"),
tags$style(type="text/css", "#retail_dashboard_ratios_table tr:last-child {font-weight:bold;}")
and this code seems to make the last row bold. (I found it randomly online). So I guess there's a way with css to customize the border as well

Comment: Try to install old version of tableHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elegant solution would probably work with a style sheet, but if it's just one table you are trying to style you could simply add CSS to the HTML header as below. More info on this can be found [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). I find that the tricky part is often to know what class to overwrite as in this case `.table>tbody>tr>td, ...`. But a simple way to find what you're looking for is to inspect the HTML at runtime, e.g. in Google Chrome you would right-click + "Inspect" anywhere in the browser window (preferably close to the element you want to style). You can then edit the style in the browser at runtime to preview how your changes to the CSS would affect the appearance off your app. I'm not very familiar with CSS either, but this is approach usually gets me a long way.

Hope this helps!

```
shinyApp(

  # --- User Interface --- #

  ui = fluidPage(

    # The below overwrites the default styling for the top border of table cells. 
    # I've changed the colour to blue from grey and the width to 3px from 1px.
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 3px solid blue; 
      }
    "))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table")
    )

  ),

  # --- Server logic --- #

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$retail_dashboard_ratios_table <- renderTable({  #
      df <- head(mtcars)
    })
  }

)
```

**Edit**

In case you want to set the style for one table only, rather than all tables in you app, you need to create your own CSS class for it. You can provide a name four class rather easily by simply writing e.g `.my_table` or `#my_table` in front of the existing CSS code above. So to complete the above example, but now with individual styling:

```
shinyApp(

  # --- User Interface --- #

  ui = fluidPage(

    # The below now creates a custum css class. 
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .my_table .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 3px solid blue; 
      }
    "))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3("Custom style table:"),
      tags$div(
        class="my_table", # set to custom class
        tableOutput("custom_table")
      ),
      h3("Default style table:"),
      tableOutput("default_table"), # No class assigned
      h3("Another default style table:"),
      tableOutput("another_default_table") # No class assigned
    )

  ),

  # --- Server logic --- #

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$custom_table <- renderTable({  #
      df <- head(mtcars)
    })

    output$default_table <- renderTable({  #
      df <- head(iris)
    })

    output$another_default_table <- renderTable({  #
      df <- head(cars)
    })
  }

)
```

Below is the output the code produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Please, allow me one clarification question. I inspected the webpage and the class assigned to the table element is "shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output".
Then, I tried to use:
tags$style(HTML('.shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output
                                                 {border-collapse: collapse;
                                                 font-size:20px;
                                                 color:red;
                                                 })) 
but this change impacts all the tables in my shiny app. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Thanks, @Angelo, I've edited the answer. The second example does what you want to achieve. Rather than overwriting the default style for all tables, in this case you want to create a custom class for that individual table. This will work in exactly the same way for the style tag you suggest in your comment. The custom class can be reused anywhere in the app in the same manner. If you start adding more CSS to your app you should consider just putting all that CSS code into a stylesheet. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for all the help so far! What you show in the code makes sense to me but somehow, when I check other tables they now show the same format as the .my_table class. Is there perhaps something missing ?

Comment: Hmm that's very strange, I've added a picture of the output produced by my code. Have you tried copying the code into your R console and running it? I've tried to make it even clearer how to assign the CSS class (and where not to). Hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Hi Patrick, I will 95% of my whole code in my initial question. I'm using your same logic and the two tables I print on the same page have the same format even though it shouldn't be the case

Comment: sorry for driving you crazy. I literally removed most of the useless things in my code and pasted what I have in my initial question above. If I run the app, both "retail_dashboard_ratios_table" as well as  "retail_dashboard_table2" show exactly the same format

Comment: I’m not sure what else to do @Angelo. You can verify that my code works, perhaps start from there and adapt it to your use case.

Comment: Sorry, I’m only now seeing that you added more code. I’m away from my laptop, but will have a look later in case you have managed to solve it by then.

Comment: I run your class and it works fine, it seems to be due to something in my class definition. Perhaps since I define the background colors of headers and rows this causes a conflict somwhere?

Comment: Patrick, I confirm my script doesn't like the fact that I customize the header and the rows of the table :/ do you think it's something easy to fix?

Comment: I fixed it! I just had to add ".my_table_aa01" to each element of the table I want to customize. THANK YOU SO MUCH Patrick !!!

Comment: @Angelo great to see you figured it out! Glad I could help